# Output the "Body" field with markup using Views PHP to be used in Views Datasource (JSON)

Tags: views, 8

We are creating an API using Views/Views Datasource and we want to output the Body field with markup already in the field not plain text. How can we do this? 
This Views_PHP approach just outputs the standard Body field as text.

```
$nid = $row->nid;
$node = node_load($nid);
$display = array('type' => 'ugc');
$output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'body', $display);
print render($output);
```

On the example below the @papermill should be a link if this was rendered on the front end.

[image: Body Field output]

Answer (score 1):

No need for Views PHP, in the settings for my JSON putout it ticks Plaintext output by default!
[image: I had Plaintext Output ticked]

UPDATE: this does answer the question but we can no longer render our REACTJS App on the front end because i presume of some kind of encoding issue with some characters inside the Body field?